# Split the string with white space and add one word to result of split string using pointer array

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers

**My code**

```
void splitStr(char *str,char *strArray[]){
    int i=0;
   char *token;
   const char s[2] = " ";
/* get the first token */
   token = strtok(str, s);

   /* walk through other tokens */
   while( token != NULL ) 
   {
      strArray[i]=token;
      token = strtok(NULL, s);
      i++;
   }
   strArray[i]=NULL;
}


void addWord(char *strArray[],char *word){
    int i;
    char *token;
    const char s[2] = " ";
    token = strtok(word,s);
    for(i = 0; strArray[i]!=NULL; i++) {
        strcat(strArray[i],token);
    }
    for(i = 0; strArray[i]!=NULL; ++i) {
        printf("%s\n",*(strArray+i));
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
   char str[200],word[100],*spldWords[20];
   int i;
   printf("Enter sentence or string\n");
   gets(str);
   splitStr(str,spldWords);
    for(i = 0; spldWords[i]!=NULL; ++i) {
        printf("%s\n", spldWords[i]);
    }
    printf("\nEnter word\n");
    gets(word);
    addWord(spldWords,word);
   return 0;
}
```

**Output for above code:**

Enter sentence or string
C programming is fun
C
programming
is
fun

Enter word
add
Caddadd
ddadd
isaddadd
ddadd

**I need output is like this**
Cadd
programmingadd
isadd
funadd
I'm struggling to solve this program. please anybody help me.
Thanks

Comment: [Never use `gets`! It is dangerous!](http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-dangerous-why-should-it-not-be-used)

Answer (score 1):

You're not allocating any strings for `spldWords`.

You declare it as an array of `char*`s of size 20.

And then you assign to it as though those strings have been allocated in `splitStr`.

You need to dynamically allocate those strings *before* you write to them.

**EDIT:**

In your `splitStr` loop you try to assign a string like this: `strArray[i]=token;` That will only assign a pointer to a location that is *hopefully* being maintained by `strtok`. You need to allocate space for a string and then copy over the *characters* pointed at by `token` to your newly allocated string:

```
strArray[i] = malloc(sizeof(char) * 200);
strcpy(strArray[i], token);
```

Anything dynamically allocated like this will need to be `free`d before you end your program. So, we need to know which elements of `spldWords` have been allocated. To do this we'll need to initialize everything in it to `NULL` and only free non-`NULL` array elements. So where you previously initialized like this: `char* spldWords[20];` you now need to initialize like this:

```
char* spldWords[20] = {};
```

Finally you need to `free` each dynamically allocated element as soon as you're through with `spldWords`. Do that like this:

```
for(i = 0; i < sizeof(spldWords) && spldWords[i] != NULL; ++i){
    free(spldWords[i]);
}
```

I've put all this into ideone.com for you to look at if need be: http://ideone.com/2yYoPp

Comment: Also, be careful with using `strcat` as this will append characters to your words. If you don't allocate enough memory there, you get some unexpected behaviour.

Comment: sorry,actually i'm new to pointer. could you solve this problem in coding

Comment: @user3691208 Generally speaking we want to limit StackOverflow.com to helping with specific problems, *not* writing code for people. But I do appreciate that you're actually making an effort on this, so I've added some code as well. This stuff is pretty foundation to C, so hopefully it makes sense. If not I can try to give basic explanation  in answer to comments, but it sounds as though you may need to make your way through a tutorial, or my comments are just going to be gibberish to you.

Comment: @user3691208 If this solved your problem I'd appreciate if you could accept by clicking the checkmark to the left of my answer.